# Pyinstaller on Mac: How to open app without opening terminal first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, pyinstaller

So I'm pretty new to Pyinstaller and trying to create an app that will run on any OS system without opening the terminal first.  So far, I've downloaded Pyinstaller and running `pyinstaller --onefile mainGUI.spec` in the terminal to generate the dist and executable.  My Spec file is as follows:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['mainGUI.pyw', 'modules/methods.py'],
             pathex=['****'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[('private_key/private_key.pem', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['numpy', 'pytz', 'dateutil', 'PyJWT', 'httplib2', 'Pysocks', 'json', 'time', 'openpyxl'],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
             win_private_assemblies=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)

def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path

dict_tree = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='mainGUI',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

I've tried the -w --noconsole and --windowed flags when generating the executable and none of that has worked.  From what I've read in the documentation those seem to be the flags to use.

Thanks in advance for any advise/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, at least for me.  Turns out something went weird with the spec file.  I just deleted that one and ran the commands again and the newly created one worked perfectly!

Hope this helps some people.